Add footer to PDF at inconsistent intervals
I have a pdf file of some lecture transcript. And I have the pager numbers each lecture starts at as below

Lecture 1-page 4
Lecture 2-page 28
Lecture 3-page 50
...

I would like to add a footer OR header at each page indicating which lecture the page belongs to - because otherwise its hard to navigate.
Ex: Add the text "Lecture 1" to all pages between 4-27, and "Lecture 2" to all pages between 28-49
Is there any command line utility that can do this ?

Try cpdf in.pdf 4-27 -add-text "Lecture 1" -bottom 20 AND -range 28-49 -add-text "Lecture 2" -bottom 20 AND ................ -o out.pdf where the dots are any additional ones. The 20 is the distance in points of the text baseline from the bottom of the page.
